# How to efficiently perform a list of transformations in place on an object in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm new to C++ and am a bit confused by how references, values, and move semantics work. I want to implement a function that can take an event, apply a list of transforms, and output the transformed event.

Here's a code snippet:

```
std::vector<Event (*)(Event)> transforms = ...;

Event process(Event baseEvent) {
    Event&& e = std::move(baseEvent);
    for(auto fn: this->transforms) {
        e = fn(e);
    }
    return e;
}
```

The requirements:

1. The `baseEvent` should not be modified in place by `process`. I believe this is achieved here since I am passing the event in by value.
2. The `process` method's copy of `baseEvent` should be modified in place by each transform. I want to be careful not to make any extra copies. Each transform function takes in the event as an rvalue reference. However, I'm not sure if this is being achieved.

I read up on move semantics and tried to reason through the code, but not sure if the requirements are being met.

Comment: Start by not bothering with the move or the `e` variable. Just use `baseEvent` as both argument and recipient of the result for each function. If your program doesn't live up to the possible requirements then you measure and profile to find the top-three bottlenecks and optimize them. If your requirements are still not fulfilled, measure and profile again to get the new top-*two* bottlenecks. Next time the new top-*one* bottleneck.

Comment: Your presentation is a bit confusing because it looks like you've mixed your own commentary with the requirements. For example, the question currently states that part of the first requirement is *"I believe this is achieved here since I am passing the event in by value"*, which really does not come across as a requirement. More confusing: is *"I want to be careful not to make any extra copies."* a requirement or your strategy for meeting the requirement? I'd suggest that after "The requirements:" you list just the requirements. Then create a new list, numbered the same, with your commentary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transformation function takes an `Event` and returns a new `Event`. It is literally impossible to build a "should modify in place" function on top of that.

So your function is already pretty much as close as you can get to what you want, except for the rvalue reference thing. There's no point in doing that. You want to `std::move` into the function, so that the argument can be move-constructed, but otherwise just assign back to the one object you already have.

```
Event process(Event e) {
    for(auto fn: this->transforms) {
        e = fn(std::move(e));
    }
    return e;
}
```

If you want the transformation functions to actually modify in place, you need to give them the ability to do so:

```
std::vector<void (*)(Event&)> transforms = ...;

Event process(Event e) {
    for(auto fn: this->transforms) {
        fn(e);
    }
    return e;
}
```